# Yii Gii with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, yii, gii

Could anyone please tell me how MongoDB can be used with YII?

How can we create controller and model functions using [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) if the database used is MongoDB?

Answer (score 2):

The way of creating controllers is same as usual but you have to use an extension to talk to mongoDB from Yii ,

You need to use [direct Mongo suite of yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/directmongosuite/)  . It is an extension which has a collection of  components for the mongoDB .

Comment: Does the `directmongosuite` work with `gii` .. have you used it?

Comment: If you are using gii , then use yiimongodbsuite dont go for directmongosuite [yiimongosuite](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/#hh5)

Comment: So the original question was about using Gii (though there was an incorrect edit today where someone thought Gii was typoed Yii) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I've used [YiiMongoDBSuite (YMDS)](https://github.com/joaorjose/YiiMongoDbSuite/tree/dev), which has some very rough support for Gii.  You can generate starter classes, but given that MongoDB does not have a fixed schema you will need to edit the model to make them useful.  There is an odd kludge that lets you generate MongoDB models from a SQL table, but this seems more effort than it's worth.

YMDS' `EMongoDocument` class extends the standard Yii `CModel` class, so this is a useful base if you want to build apps with CRUDS.

The unfortunate caveat is that YMDS is no longer maintained by the original author, and there are a few [community forks](https://github.com/canni/YiiMongoDbSuite/network) to chose between.